# Report SSRS- How can I put textbox or value in the center of doughnut chart?

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a *Doughnut Chart* in my report in *SSRS* and I want to put the total percentage value into the center of this chart. 
This chart consists of different percentages of different categories.What I want is putting percentage of Total into the center of chart.
Is this possible ?

Comment: hello, welcome to stackoverflow, please consider reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As you can see it is my first question then why did you put negative point on it? You are man who want to help or who want to just gain points ?

Comment: I get no points when downvote, you just need to improve your question